# "from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser" gives Error: ImportError: cannot import name 'SkipError'

Tags: python, api, django-rest-framework

I'm developing an API.
But this command "from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser" gives me an error-
[Please view- This is the screenshot of the error in jupyter terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pin2n.png)

```
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers/fields.py", line 20, in <module>
    from rest_framework.exceptions import SkipError
ImportError: cannot import name 'SkipError'
```

I updated djangorestframework and updated pip and python versions as well. I even added 'rest_framework' to Installed Apps but still the error is there.

Can anyone please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typically, rest_framework and other third-party apps should follow the built-in Django apps. DRF's template tags don't try to `import SkipError from rest_framework.exceptions`.

Do you install `restapi` package? I think you should check all your package again, somewhere import like that so you got the error.